# Managing Large Conference Sub-Programs in CiviCRM

Tags: custom-fields

I work for an organization that has a long history of putting on large conferences and we want the workshops and panels of these conferences to stored in CiviCRM connected to those who spoke and attended. Where would be the best place to do this? Should I create a Custom Field for Programs or should they each be activities so I can have more than one contact record connected to it?

Answer (score 1):

CiviEvent works marvellously for conferences. As Erik suggests use different roles for your delegates, speakers etc. From Civi help: "Participant Role:
The Role you select here is automatically assigned to people when they register online for this event (usually the default 'Attendee' role). You can also allow people to choose a Role by creating a Profile with the Participant Role field. Then include that Profile when you configure the Online Registration page for this event.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve. You will probably need to explain in some more detail. My first reaction is: use the participant role so you can see which role the contact had on which conference?

Comment: The way the conference works is there are breakout sessions. So we wouldn't create a whole "event" for each session right? So how would I handle that because these breakout sessions are what we want to keep track of. You can't create sub-events so would I make it an activity? Or a custom field in their profiles?